# FileNotFoundException when loading an Image I just captured

Tags: java, android, exception, android-bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I'm making an app that allows a user to capture and image and then use that image on a puzzle. I can use the camera successfully but after image capture, when I'm supposed to be taken to the puzzle screen where the image is loaded from local storage, I get an FNF exception. (I have a section in the app that shows the images that the user can use for the puzzle and the newly captured image shows up there - after restarting the app since it has crashed).

My code is as follows

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String filepath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {


    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath),
            reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
}
```

Exception is thrown on the `return` line. Please help me resolve this. Thank you.
 Edit: wrapped try catch around `return` line and now Logcat displays

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
    at apps.mine.puzzle.Board.countTileSize(Board.java:60)
    at apps.mine.puzzle.PlayPuzzleActivity.onCreate(PlayPuzzleActivity.java:138)
```

Comment: Add the full traceback , like is it a NullPointerException ?

Comment: Hi @Ben.Ayoub yeah, it is a NullPointerException. i'll add it above

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue , this will fix it:

```
if(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image[position])!=null)
{
    Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image[position]), 32, 32, true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
else
{
    Log.d("TAG", "unable to decode");
}
```

the main cause of the issue is that `decodeResource` is returning you a null for one of the following reasons :

1. The image file is corrupt
2. No read permission
3. There is not enough memory to decode the file
4. The resource does not exist
5. Invalid options specified in the options variable.

**UPADTE**

if you don't want to decode the file twice as @Zoe pointed out, you can modify the code of `decodeResource` so it'll null-check without having to do it twice, like this :

```
public class BitmapScalingHelper
{
    public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight)
    {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight);
        options = new Options();
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        if(unscaledBitmap == null)
        {
            Log.e("ERR","Failed to decode resource" + resId + " " + res.toString());
            return null;
        }
        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Don't do that... You're decoding the file twice, which just slows down the app without much of an improvement or in any way patching it. null-check yes, but store a cache variable to avoid decoding twice

Comment: It is. I follow the code you provided. I'm going through the debugger and my `options.inSampleSize` is evaluated to 0. I'm following up on that